# How can I include a unicode symbol in a Gollum wiki (Sinatra app)?

Tags: unicode, sinatra, gollum-wiki

I'm trying to use a Unicode character in a Gollum wiki, but it gets escaped - the `&` gets turned into `$amp;`.

Is there something like Rails' `.html_safe` for Gollum or for Sintra apps in general?

Answer (score 1):

I’m sure it uses UTF-8, which means you could just paste in the symbol itself? In most cases this is quite practical… Only for non-breaking-spaces etcetera I still use unicode character entitities.

It could be there is an option to escape input text, but probably not since Gollum has to run on GitHub… this means they are careful about sanitising input.